# tslint error: Asterik in jsdoc must be aligned

Tags: angularjs, typescript, jsdoc, tslint

I keep getting this tslint error and don't see what's wrong with the code. Does anybody see an issues with the jsdoc asteriks below not being aligned correctly:

```
/**
 * @ngdoc directive
 * @module ers.components.button
 * @scope
 * @transclude
 * @data
 * @binding
 * @name ersButton
 * @restrict E
 * @constructor
 * 
 * @description
 * 
 * A button performs the defined action when the user clicks it.
 * 
 * - Buttons can only consist of text and/or an icon.
 * - Buttons must contain either a click event, an href, an ui-sref, or a type (for form actions).
 * - Buttons labels should be clear. Limit the button text (less is more).
 * 
 * ### Usage
 * 
 * - Use <b>Primary Buttons</b> for primary actions (for example, "Submit", "Login", or "Save"). 
 * Avoid having multiple primary buttons on the same screen.
 * - Use <b>Secondary Buttons</b> for secondary actions that accompany the primary call-to-action (for example, "Reset" or "Cancel").
 * - Use <b>Icon Buttons</b> only for special use cases where standard label buttons are too large to use (for example, Tool Bars).
 *   
 * ### Examples
 * 
 * #### Standard Buttons
 * 
 * Primary and secondary buttons.
 *
 * <code-editor identifier="example1" data-title="Basic Buttons" html-content-url="demos/ersButton/basic/index.html" 
 * js-content-url="demos/ersButton/basic/script.js" css-content-url="demos/ersButton/basic/styles.css" 
 * content-mode="html"></code-editor>
 */
```

Just about every line below is giving me that same error.

Comment: Your markdown has a mix of tabs and spaces and the asterisks don't appear be be aligned in the markdown. What's enforced by the `jsdoc-format` rule is described [here](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/jsdoc-format/),

Comment: Yea there must have been some spacing issues that was throwing it off. I ended up just deleting all of it and typing it over again and it passed the linter. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

In my Angular 9 project I was able to get the lint error

`filename.ts:13:1 - asterisks in jsdoc must be aligned`

from

```
/**
 *
 */
```

fixed

```
/*
*
*/
```

Not sure why because the [js-doc rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/jsdoc-format/) for multiline comments says it requires two asterisks.

Answer (score 4):

From [jsdoc-format](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/jsdoc-format/) rule description:

> The following rules are enforced for JSDoc comments (comments starting
>   with /**):
>
> - each line contains an asterisk and asterisks must be aligned
> - each asterisk must be followed by either a space or a newline (except for the first and the last)
> - the only characters before the asterisk on each line must be whitespace characters
> - one line comments must start with /** and end with */

As I see from your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39988028/tslint-error-asterik-in-jsdoc-must-be-aligned#comment67295090_39988028) you had spacing issues.

Comment: so what's the problem in question ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue:

error:

```
/**
*
*
* 
*/
```

fix:

```
/**
 *
 *
 * 
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though it looks like aligning the stars wasn't your issue, I just made this little script to fix all your typescript files: https://github.com/Marr11317/starAligner.

With the hope that some people will find it helpful...