# React imports tsint asterisks in jsdoc must be aligned

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tslint

I'm trying to build a simple React app with TypeScript.
The project was created with
`create-react-app weather-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts`
[Project git repo](https://github.com/optmzer/weather-react) and I'm getting an error from tslint: `(7,1): asterisks in jsdoc must be aligned`

Using VS Code Version: 1.25.1, I tried:
1 - to sort the imports alphabetically - did not work
2 - to disable jdocs rules using `/* tslint:disable:ordered-imports jsdoc-format completed-docs */` - also did not work.
3 - I tied to break imports into modules by commenting out some lines - did not work
4 - edited tslint.json with`"rules": {
    "no-console": {
      "severity": "none",
      "options": [
          "debug",
          "info",
          "log",
          "time",
          "timeEnd",
          "trace"
      ]
  }
  }`

- the error did not go away.
5 - tried to add actual jsdoc line at the top of the file like so:

```
/**
 * This app shows local weather based on browser location.
 */
import { AccessTime } from '@material-ui/icons';
import * as React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import drizzleDay from './img/weather-drizzle-day.png';
import fewClouds from './img/weather-few-clouds.png';
import { getCity } from './services/servicesAPI';
import SmallWeather from './smallWeather/smallWeather';
```

The linter stuck on line 7:1 which is now `import * as service from './services/servicesAPI';`

What I want to do is to start the app

Here is the code of App.tsx

```
import { AccessTime } from '@material-ui/icons';
import * as React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import drizzleDay from './img/weather-drizzle-day.png';
import fewClouds from './img/weather-few-clouds.png';
import * as service from './services/servicesAPI';
import SmallWeather from './smallWeather/smallWeather';

const iconURL = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/10d.png";

class App extends React.Component<any, any> {
  constructor(props: any){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        city_name: "Auckland",
        current_temp: 30,
        current_time: Date.now()
      }
  }

  public render() {
    // assemble options object for toLocaleTimeString() method
    const options = { 
      hour12: false, 
    }
    service.getCity("Auckland");

    const timestamp = new Date(this.state.current_time).toLocaleTimeString("en-NZ", options);

    const data1 = {
      // Had to manually sort it in alphbet. order.
      date: this.state.current_time,
      iconSrc: iconURL,
      temp: 45
    }

    const data2 = {
      date: this.state.current_time,
      iconSrc: drizzleDay,
      temp: 28
    }

    const data3 = {
      date: this.state.current_time,
      iconSrc: fewClouds,
      temp: 30
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to Your Local Weather App</h1>
        </header>
        <div className="mail-view">
          <h3>{this.state.city_name}</h3>
          <p>{this.state.current_temp}<span>C|F</span></p>
          <div className="current-time">
            <AccessTime className="current-time-icon"/>
            <span>{timestamp}</span>
          </div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </div>
        <div className="grid-view">
          <SmallWeather data={data1}/>
          <SmallWeather data={data2}/>
          <SmallWeather data={data3}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Check this thread. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39988028/tslint-error-asterik-in-jsdoc-must-be-aligned

Comment: Thank you for the answer I have already red that. As I'm not writing any jsdoc I do not understand how it is related to the case of `import`

Comment: It is not the solution, but the missing `space` before the closing comment will not make the rule-disabling work? /* tslint:disable:ordered-imports jsdoc-format completed-docs */

Comment: Fixed the typo in `/* tslint:disable:ordered-imports jsdoc-format completed-docs */`. But still no luck. With or without the space it still shows `asterisks in jsdoc must be aligned` on exactly the same line even if I brake imports with comments `// internal modules`.

Comment: The actual error is in your `https://github.com/optmzer/weather-react/blob/master/src/services/servicesAPI.tsx` it is full with commented out code which can be interpreted as Jdoc comments because they are starting with `/**`. So you need to fix that file and not the App.tsx

Comment: Good idea. I just tied to remove all comments from the App.tsx but it did not work. :-( I even tried to add actual jsdoc line before and after the import tslint still stuck on the same 7:1 line even though imports moved down.

Comment: I did found a workaround. by removing `tslint-config-prettier` from tslint.json where now is `"extends": ["tslint:recommended", "tslint-react"],` But not sure if it is a good idea to remove configs from tslint. I managed to start the app though.